# Javascript IE mouse events restricted to original recipient?

Tags: javascript, events, mouse, mouseevent, mousemove

I have an info overlay that works great in Chrome and FF. It is a div containing a table (for border image layout) and then a central content div. I trigger mousedown on the appropriate border table cells.

Once this happens, a different div is brought to the front with z-index, and that passes along the mousemove and mouseup events to handle dragging the info bubble around. Once the mouseup is fired, the info bubble puts the "event" div back to where it was.

I also follow the same process for dragging the lower right corner of the bubble to resize it. Again, works in Chrome and FF, but fails in IE.

IE seems to be restricting the event triggers to the info div. If the mouse manages to move outside the div (from dragging faster then the events fire/update), the info overlay no longer receives mousemove events. However, if I move the mouse back over the overlay (without releasing the button) it continues to receive mouse events.

Edit: In creating some example code (the current functionality is split across several JS modules), it worked in IE. As soon as I find the difference between my example code and the actual code, I will update again.

Edit/Answer: (SO wont let a new user answer their own question in this time span...)
Still not sure what the actual problem was. (If you ask me, a div with a z-index of 100 should be receiving mouse events just fine?)

My solution was to fix my mouse event handling such that I could attach my mousemove and mouseup to the parent div (as should have been done in the first place) for all dragging/resizing behaviors I wanted to set up.

The problem was due to a newbie approach to the events and having stopPropagation() in too many locations preventing me from taking such an approach. (I wanted text, etc in my info box to be selectable).

I adjusted the code so that my text containers only had to stop propagation on mousedown instead of all the mouse events.

Comment: You need to post some example code that replicates the problem.  We can't guess what the problem is without knowing more.